# Xls file data not loaded into application using jmeter

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I read the blogs and user documentation .

As per the scenario ,

I need to upload a xls file and need to check the performance how much time it is taking to upload the file with min and max file  size.

So I followed the below steps:

1.Recorded the script Under HTTP Request (where the file getting loaded )

2.Changed the "Implementation" to Java and "Method" also to POST

3.Checked the check box for multi-part/form-data for POST

4.Added the file path and MIME Type respectively

5.Increased the value in properties file for httpsampler.max_redirects=10 because Response code: 302 was found in the reports.After  increasing the value also still am getting 302 as response (URL is redirecting)

---

When I run the test, run is success and no errors as well.

When checked the application manually whether the data is loaded or not .

Am not able to see the data uploaded by Jmeter.  But reports are generated without error.

So in this case am not sure whether we can consider the reports or not ?  Moreover data is not loaded into the application ?

Can you please help me with why the data is not loaded into the application ? Is their any other workaround we need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that JMeter is smart enough to capture file upload request so I wouldn't "change" request method just make sure that you use full path to your .xls file in the relevant request.

A couple of troubleshooting tips:

1. Temporarily add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request/response data details.
2. Inspect `jmeter.log` file for any warnings or errors
3. Follow recommendations from [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide.

Comment: ,Thanks .I didn't handle Cookie .I added Cookie Manager then the data  was loaded  was succesfully into application . I verified as well with mutliple Iterations.